# Where to put the converter method in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, architecture

In general, the controller is in the presentation layer which get the data from model and sent to `view`.

Now, my controller get a data, but I need to transfer the format to the javascript style which can be used on the view. For example, I have a list of `X`, and a list of `Y`, and I need to create two kind of tables which can be directly used in the view. So I need a method called `create_table X Y`, For example:

```
def create_table X Y
    @table1 = .....
    @table2 = .....
end
```

and the `@table1` and `@table2` is used in the view.

So my problem is, where to put this function?

In controller? I thought most of the method in the controller means the action which related to a specific view.

in the private in controller? I saw that in controller, there are methods such as `set_XXX` , `XXX_params` which are private, if I put the method here, the instance in the method can be directly access by the view?

in the helper? I saw some people put the method here and include the helper in controller, but as I know, the method in helper is used only by the view.

Can anyone help me? thanks!

Comment: This sounds to me like a *presenter* or a *decorator*. I would add a `presenters` folder to the `app` folder and would place a class into that folder.

Comment: put function in `helper`

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you put this kind of "helper" on lib folder like: './lib/my_parser.rb'

Also, you can turn a bunch of logic in a gem.

Some reference:
http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/02/07/what-code-goes-in-the-lib-directory/

Answer (score 0):

In Rails a typical convention to follow is to think of Models as classes for retrieving and modifying information in your database, think of Controllers as classes for building instance variables based on http request parameters and calling Model methods, and think of Views as presentation templates for displaying the information that is stored in those instance variables that the Controllers create.

With this mindset, what you are pitching as a `create_table` method should surely exist on the view side of Rails' MVC architecture, not in the controller.

Depending on the complexity of this `create_table` method, you would either use a view **partial** or a view **helper** method.

---

#### View Helpers

View helper methods are defined in modules under `app/helpers/my_helper.rb`.

Decent writeup on view helpers: http://www.rails-dev.com/custom-view-helpers-in-rails-4

#### View Partials

View partials are defined as templates under the views folder and have filenames prefixed by underscores, e.g. `app/views/some_folder/_my_partial.html.erb`

Rails' guide to partials: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

---

This writeup does a good job of explaining where to put code fragments in Rails:

http://codefol.io/posts/Where-Do-I-Put-My-Code

Comment: Sorry, thanks for your answer, may be I didn't explain clearly about my question. The method `create_table` is not directly used in view, it's used in controller. The example I have edited in the question

Comment: Okay, that would break the conventions of an MVC architecture.  That said, you could still write your method in a view helper module.  Then, in your controller, include the helper module: `include MyHelper`